# p:commandButton or p:button with actionListener and outcome?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, actionlistener, commandbutton

I'm using PrimeFaces and have a Save button, basically a maintenanceTask is sent to my page, I edit it within here, then press Save and it should be saved to the database and then redirected to the original page. I have a working Save method, but can't seem to get both the navigation and method to fire off.

```
    <p:commandButton value="#{message.commonButtonSave}"
        title="#{message.commonSaveTooltip}"
        rendered="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.screenMode == 'editTasks'}"          
        disabled="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.outstandingEditCount != 0}"
        action="/definemaintenance/MaintenanceTasksActivity"
        actionListener="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.save}" >           
    </p:commandButton>
```

There is what I have at the minute, but I have tried many different variations on this including p:button and p:commandButton, listener/actionListener, target/outcome/action etc...

Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform action, and navigate afterwards, use `action` attribute and return the navigation rule as a result.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{message.commonButtonSave}"
    title="#{message.commonSaveTooltip}"
    rendered="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.screenMode == 'editTasks'}"          
    disabled="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.outstandingEditCount != 0}"
    action="#{maintenanceTaskEnquiryBean.save}">           
</p:commandButton>
```

The `save()` method would look something like this

```
public String save() {
    // perform whatever you need to, and then
    return "<some navigataion rule>";
}
```

The return string should open the desired page `/definemaintenance/MaintenanceTasksActivity`.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there anywhere you could direct me to learn about how to write a navigation rule?

Comment: @hello123 [This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_page_navigation.htm) seems to cover JSF navigation quite well.

Comment: Funnily enough, that's the tutorial I've been reading through this afternoon. When I use return="MaintenanceTasksActivity" nothing happens though, I've also tried /definemaintenance/MaintenanceTasksActivity and definemaintenance/MaintenanceTasksActivity with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be beacuse my Bean is ViewScoped rather than RequestScoped?

Comment: Shouldn't have anything with the scope of the bean. It all depends on your project structure. If you return `MaintenanceTasksActivity`, it will look for `MaintenanceTasksActivity.xhtml`, do you have that (it is case sensitive)? Check out [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/) (if you didn't already :) ) for basic stuff. Try to have that basic navigation working, maybe on some test pages, and when it gets clear to you on how it works, apply it to your real case.